# Drop down list with foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, html, select, foreach

I'm trying to make a drop down list with PHP using a foreach loop to loop through the data. This works without a drop down when I was displaying the results in a table so the loop does work.

It seems the drop down list gets populated (as the list expands/contracts when I've added new fields in for testing) but no data is actually shown. I only need to show one field, though. Here's my code:

```
    <select name="language_select">
        <?php foreach($this->getContent('languages') as $language => $value) : ?>
            <option value="<?($language['name']);?>"></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
```

So it fetches an array and tries to return the data, pretty simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is short PHP tag enabled on your server? Try changing `<?` to `<?php` and see if that helps.

Comment: @AmalMurali does it matter?

Comment: You need to `echo` the value

Comment: You have to echo the name within the tags as well as in the `value` like: `<option value="<?($language['name']);?>"><?($language['name']);?></option>` (are you echoing the variables?)

Comment: where's echo ? or print ?

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $language['name'];?>"></option>

Comment: @Venkat that generates an error 'expected: expression'

Comment: @CiaranReen you echo you should use the [short echo tag syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). I have an example in my answer below. It is enabled by default in php 5.4 and available if the short open tag configuration directive is set in versions before that

Comment: What does `print_r($this->getContent('languages'));` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working, with Orangepills help (thanks), with this:

```
<option value="<?= ($language['name']);?>"><?= ($language['name']) ?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure of the composition the return of $this->getContent('languages') but I think this is what you need.

```
<select name="language_select">
    <?php foreach($this->getContent('languages') as $language) : ?>
        <option value="<?= urlencode($language['name']);?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($language["name"]) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This works! With one slight problem: it is displaying the id field (language_id) instead of the name field, as specified in the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing gets returned. I've added in the 'languages_id' field to test what comes back, and now each field is duplicated i.e 0,0,1,1,2,2 etc.

Comment: I've viewed the array in Chrome, and each element in the array is matched correctly. I.e [0] is matched to [language_id]1, [name]English, [shortcode]en and so on. So I'm not sure why it is displaying just the ID field.

Comment: @CiaranReen Again what does `print_r($this->getContent('languages'));` show

Comment: If you cared to read my above comment I said 'nothing gets returned'.

Comment: @ClaranReen Something must get returned if your are able to loop through it with foreach.